$C\ell_{16}$ basis vectors as tensor products
Given a Clifford algebra $C\ell_{16}$, it is known that $C\ell_{16} \simeq C\ell_{8} \otimes C\ell_{8}$.
Does this imply that the basis vectors of $C\ell_{16}$ can be written somehow as tensor products of basis vectors of $C\ell_{8}$? I've been trying to find such a representation but I'm stuck.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Nevermind, just found one. If $e_i$ is a basis of $C\ell_{8}$ and $I=e_1 \ldots e_8$ is the volume element, then $\{e_i \otimes I, 1 \otimes e_j\}$ forms a basis of $C\ell_{16}$.
